# php mysql results backslashes removed

Tags: php, mysql, regex

I have a table with file names and some other information in it. When I run the following query:

```
select * from `documentinfo` WHERE `num`='40217'
```

I get the results correctly:

```
Array
(
    [num] => 40217
    [datetime] => 2011-09-15 15:22:07
    [date] => 2011-09-15
    [filename] => C:\redoak\DocumentsIN\Filer\8883894460_3044564210_07334802020001.mp3
)
```

When I run the query:

```
QUERY:`filename` REGEXP '^C:\\redoak\\DocumentsIN\\Filer'
```

I get:

```
Array
(
    [num] => 35910
    [datetime] => 2010-12-03 17:34:38
    [date] => 2010-12-03
    [filename] => c:
edoakDocumentsINFiler8883894460_3043926485_05863748580001.mp3
)
```

Notice that the results have the \ removed from the folder name.

I used the following php with both to display this:

```
while ($row = array_change_key_case(mysql_fetch_assoc($webquery), CASE_LOWER)) 
{
    print_r($row);  
}
```

---

Query for any num works just fine. The regexp query works if the pattern does not contain a backslash. If it contains a backslash it works but the data returned from the table is missing it's back slashes. Even though the query finds the correct records. Thank Oak

Is the the problem: The character_set_results
Does a regexp query return a different character set results by default then a = query?

---

I tried the following to change the character set to see what happened:

```
mysql_query("SET character_set_results = 'utf8', character_set_client = 'utf8', character_set_connection = 'utf8', character_set_database = 'utf8', character_set_server = 'utf8'") or die("ERROR SETTING CHAR SET");      
echo '<pre>debug: encoding=', mysql_client_encoding(), '</pre>';

$webquery=mysql_query($query);

echo '<pre>debug: encoding=', mysql_client_encoding(), '</pre>';
```

it always indicates latin1

I used `mysql_set_charset('utf8');` and it changed to `utf8` but the results did not change.

Comment: And what do you get on ` select * from documentinfo WHERE num='35910'`?

Comment: it returns correctly with the backslashes in the file name.

Answer (score 2):

MySQL interprets a backslash character as an *escape character*. For backslash in a query use double backslash `\\`

Comment: Thanks, however the results are the same, the query works as far as locating the correct records. However the data returned has been altered, the backslashes and some other characters that they appear to "escape" have been removed... before I get the results from a regexp or like query, but not from a = query Thanks! Oak